# Xamarin Forms Android GC loop

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, garbage-collection, xamarin.android

I'm caching entities from the SQLite db by using the SQLite.Net Async library because they are frequently needed. When I navigate to a certain page (explained below) which uses loads of bindings to display the entity an 'infinite' GC loop occurs.

[image: NurseryFull]

To cache the entities I'm using the

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection.Table<T>().ToListAsync()
```

and store them in a

```
ConcurrentDictionary<Type, IEnumerable<IEntity>>
```

After this I use

```
Parallel.ForEach()
```

with loads of reflection and recursion to map each entity. This process seems to be rather fast...

When I navigate to the troublesome page it retrieves the cached entities and displays them in a ListView. When an entity is tapped the information about the entity is should be displayed to the screen via bindings. Right when the user taps the screen the loop begins.

After returning from the grocery store I see it's still not done.
[image: NurseryFull]

I've tested this on an emulator running with HAXM, 2GBRAM, 256Heap size and a Galaxy Tab of which I don't know the type anymore both having the same problem (altough the tablet can handle more entities before the loop begins).

I know this probably is not enough information and I'll provide more but I just don't know where to look or what could cause this.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Yours,

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I will work on that today!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the problem. At first I thought it had something to do with the amount of entities I was caching because the problem only occured when the amount of entities reached X. When I commented out the XAML piece by piece to test why the page was so troublesome I discovered the real issue.

I have created a [GIST](https://gist.github.com/noelheesen/a0ce7d27d3fb8038dad117ffafaf270e) to show what happened.

TLDR;
I run multiple Validation Behaviors and they were conflicting with each other.